# Confusion about job portal accomplishments section

Tags: resume, job-search

I'm applying for a job at a big company. They have their own job portal. There is a section where you have to input your previous work and education experience. In addition to the general facts like institution and number of years, there is a text box that wants me to input my accomplishments at previous work experiences.

There is then also a place to upload your resume and cover letter as well as additional documents that may help.

How would I fill out the accomplishments section without it being a regurgitation of my resume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked,

> How would I fill out the accomplishments section without it being a regurgitation of my resume?

In general, you don't need to be concerned about it being a regurgitation. In practice, it's common for that text box to essentially be a *cut and paste* from an applicant's resume.

This leads to an obvious question, *why would employers make me do this?* The answer is, it makes it easier for them to organize your data in their talent management system. A resume is a great tool to make your work history human-readable - it's usually formatted to make the information easy to read on standard letter-sized paper. However, it's *hard* to get a machine to ingest that information into an organized, searchable, structured database. So, instead of trying to get a computer to parse your resume, the system asks *you* to do the work of parsing it out for storage in the database, *and* providing a nice, human-readable document.

Answer (score 3):

This is based on my personal experience applying to companies with their own job portals (Software development) and interactions with HR when filling such forms.

Don't worry too much about the box, pick any top X things (can be top 3 or 5) that stand out in your resume, and put it there. Your resume and Cover Letter are there to help the HR/hiring manager shortlist you if required.